# VBA Unique Distinct Lists

Tags: vba, excel

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I've put together the following code which I'm hoping to use, to extract data from a 'Source' "AllData" sheet and paste this information to a 'Destination' "Direct Activities" sheet.

To be more specific:

- I would like the script to look for the text value **"DIR"** in column **E** on the 'Destination' sheet,
- When it finds this, copy the values from columns **D** and **B**, and create unique distinct lists for both, then,
- Paste the value from column **D** to column **B**, and column **B** to column **C** on the 'Destination' sheet.

In addition I would like the script to sum all of the manday figures from column **I** on the 'Source' sheet, placing them under the relevant month on the 'Destination' sheet.

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, strProject As String, RLOB As String, RDate As Date, RVal As Single
    Dim BlnProjExists As Boolean, ws As Worksheet, DI As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Const StartRow As Long = 5

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set DI = Sheets("Direct Activities")


    With Sheets("AllData").Range("E3")
        For i = 1 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
            strProject = .Offset(i, 0)
            RDate = .Offset(i, 3)
            RVal = .Offset(i, 4)
            RLOB = .Offset(i, -3)

         If InStr(.Offset(i, 0), "DIR") > 0 And RVal > 0 Then
            strProject = .Offset(i, -1)
            RLOB = .Offset(i, -3)
            With DI.Range("B1")
                If .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                    .Offset(1, 0) = strProject
                    j = 1
                Else
                    BlnProjExists = False
                    For j = 1 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
                         If .Offset(j, 0) = strProject And .Offset(j, 1) = RLOB Then
                            BlnProjExists = True
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next j
                        If BlnProjExists = False Then
                          .Offset(j, 0) = strProject
                        End If
                End If
                Select Case Format(RDate, "mmm yy")
                    Case "Apr 13"
                        m = 1
                    Case "May 13"
                        m = 2
                    Case "Jun 13"
                        m = 3
                    Case "Jul 13"
                        m = 4
                    Case "Aug 13"
                        m = 5
                    Case "Sep 13"
                        m = 6
                    Case "Oct 13"
                        m = 7
                    Case "Nov 13"
                        m = 8
                    Case "Dec 13"
                        m = 9
                    Case "Jan 14"
                        m = 10
                    Case "Feb 14"
                        m = 11
                    Case "Mar 14"
                        m = 12
                End Select
                        m = m + 1
                 .Offset(j, m) = .Offset(j, m) + RVal
            End With


         End If
        Next i
    End With

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

I'm able to paste the values in column **B** on the 'Destination' sheet, but the values are incorrectly repeated multiple times, and I've been unable to copy the value from column **B** on the 'Source' sheet to column **C** on the 'Destination' sheet .

I can however sum the manday figure from column I on the 'Source' sheet to the correct month on the 'Destination' sheet.

I've uploaded the file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ex50xqkq20jx350/Excel%20Extract%20150913.xlsm) with the 'Source' "AllData" sheet and the "Direct Activities" 'Destination sheet. If you select the button on the "Macros" sheet you can run the macro.

In addition I've included another sheet "Expected Activities" showing what I want to achieve with the macro.

I just wondered whether someone could possibly look at this please and offer some guidance on how I may go about achieving this.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: To begin with, why loop through the rows to find the text? Why not use `.Find` and `.FindNext`. See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: Can you please post some sample source data?

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post. I'm relatively new to VBA, and I've had a little help to come up with the script which I've posted, which I've built onto, so I wasn't aware of other ways to do this. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: What you are trying to do is relatively very simple and we would be glad to help you if you get stuck.. having a look at the file now :)

Comment: Hi @Joe, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. The sample 'Source' data is shown on the "AllData" tab or the file which I posted the link to. Any problems with this, please don't hesitate to get in touch. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout, thank you very much for the update. May I ask please, if at all possible, that the basis of my code is left intact because I understand the script, and I may want to include more text values to search and extract the information for at a later date. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: @IRHM Sorry, I missed that link.  I'll take a look.

Comment: I don't see DIR in any sheet...

Comment: Hi @SiddharthRout, thank you for coming back to me with this. If you look at column E on the 'AllData" sheet, you can see that there are cells containing "DIR". Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few problems with this code.

In this line:
`If .Offset(j, 0) = strProject And .Offset(j, 1) = RLOB Then`

You're looking for an existing match on columns B & C, but you're only populating column B.  You need to set it with:

```
.Offset(1, 0) = strProject
.Offset(1, 1) = RLOB 'added line
```

and:

```
.Offset(j, 0) = strProject
.Offset(j, 1) = RLOB ' added line
```

Now, this line:
`With DI.Range("B1")`

will start populating rows at the top of the sheet, which I assume you don't want.  Change it to "B4".  Since this changes the number of rows in an empty table, you also need to change:

`If .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = 1 Then`
to
`If .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = 3 Then`

and:
`For j = 1 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1`
to
`For j = 1 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 3`

Though my preference would be to start at Range("B4") and use .End(xlDown) to select the area to search in.

When I ran the script with the following changes made, it produced same results as your "Expected" sheet:

```
        With DI.Range("B4") ' changed from b1
            If .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = 3 Then ' changed from 3
                .Offset(1, 0) = strProject
                .Offset(1, 1) = RLOB ' added
                j = 1
            Else
                BlnProjExists = False
                For j = 1 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 3
                     If .Offset(j, 0) = strProject And .Offset(j, 1) = RLOB Then
                        BlnProjExists = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
                    If BlnProjExists = False Then
                      .Offset(j, 0) = strProject
                      .Offset(j, 1) = RLOB ' added
                    End If
            End If
```

Comment: Hi @Joe, thank you so very much for taking the time to work on this. The solution works great! Thank you also for the explanation, it's extremely helpful. All the very best and kind regards

Comment: Hi @Joe, I'm very sorry to trouble you, & I hope you may pick this up. You kindly helped me out with the above solution yesterday, & the code works great. Unfortunately, I've had to make a change to my destination sheet, so the header row is now row 6 as opposed to row 4, so the data starts on row 7 instead of 5. I've tried making the changes to this row ` With DI.Range("B6"), but I can't seem to get it to work. Would it be possible please for you to provide some guidance on how I need to make the change. Could I also trouble you please to add some more notes to the code. Many thanks & regards

Comment: @IRHM The `With DI..` line set the start of the data, so it should be `Range("B7")` if that's where the data is.  Also the following line should change to `.Count = 6`, which is the number of rows in an empty region.

Comment: Hi @Joe, thank you very much for coming back to me with this, it's greatly appreciated. I've tried the suggestion you kindly made, and unfortunately this no longer lists the correct number of entries. I'm really sorry to trouble you again with this. Would it help if I posted another file? Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Hi @Joe, just a very quick note to say that I've fixed the problem. I changed `With DI.Range("B1")` to B6 and left the `count.` at 3. Once again sincere thanks for all your time, trouble and patience. Kind regards